# How I can to draw the digraph with biparitiion $A$ and $B$

Tags: tikz-pgf

I wish to draw the following Figure:

[image: Figure]

Look the code that I did:

```
 \documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
            chains,
            decorations.markings,
            fit,
            shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 7mm and 21mm,
start chain = going below,
U/.style = {circle, draw, fill=#1,
    inner sep=0pt, minimum size=1.5mm, 
node contents={}},
 V/.style = {U, on chain},
 every edge/.style = {decoration={markings,
          mark=at position .5 with {\arrow{Straight Barb}}},
        draw, postaction={decorate}
        },
 FIT/.style = {ellipse, draw, thick, inner xsep=1.5em, yshift=-1ex, fit=#1},            ->-/.style = {decoration={markings,
             mark=at position .5 with {\arrow{Straight Barb}}},
             draw, postaction={decorate}
             },
node distance = 4mm and 25mm
]
% vertices
\foreach \i [count=\j from 0] in {1,2,3}%
{
\node (n1\j) [V];
\node (n2\j) [U, above right=of n1\j
];
}
\node (n23) [U,right=of n12,
];
\node (n13) [on chain]      {$\vdots$};
\node (n24) [right=of n13] {$\vdots$};
\node (n14) [V
% ,label=left:{$y_{i}$}
];
\node (n25) [U,right=of n14
% , label=right:{$z_{j}$}
];

% connections 
\foreach \i [count=\j from 0] in {1}%
{
\draw   (n2\j) edge (n1\j) ;
\draw   (n1\j) edge (n2\i);
 }
 \foreach \i [count=\j] in {2,3}%
 {
 \draw[blue]   (n2\j) edge (n1\j) ;
 \draw[blue]   (n1\j) edge (n2\i);
 }

 \draw  (n14) edge (n25);
 \node [ellipse, fit=(n20) (n21),label=right:$X_1$, draw] {};
 \node [circle, fit=(n23) (n25),label=right:$X_2$, draw] {};
 \node [ellipse, fit=(n10) (n13),label=above:$A$, draw] {};
 \node [ellipse, fit=(n20) (n24),label=above:$B$, draw] {};
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{figure}
 \end{document}
```

But the generated Figure is different of image that I annexed.
Follow the Figure generate by latex code with bipartite graph with partition $I$ and $S-I$:

[image: Generated Figure]

How I can to solved it?

Comment: Please make your code **compliable** !

Comment: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that

Comment: The my question is different of this. Has  has the sets $X_1$ and $X_2$ for to draw this I'm having difficulty.

Comment: In the generated figure, $X_2$ not is inside of the set $S-I$.

Comment: You may as well replace circle by ellipse in node options.